# increase bokeh axis ticks font size and property to bold

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, bokeh

How to change the font size of the axis markers and make that bold for the following figure ? Figure is plotted with the bokeh library in python. Is there a way to get the attributes of the images like gcf where we can append the new values ?

[image: Bokeh figure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the properties of the axis that have names starting with `major_label_text_`. The documentation: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/axes.html#bokeh.models.axes.Axis.major_label_standoff

Some example:

```py
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

p1 = figure()
p1.xaxis.major_label_text_color = 'red'
p1.xaxis.major_label_text_font_size = '20px'
p1.line([0, 1], [0, 1])

show(p1)
```